# Sphinx autodoc show-inheritance: How to skip undocumented, intermediate bases?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have a three-layered class structure like this:

```
class Super(object):
    """This class is documented."""

class Intermediate(Super):
    pass

class Sub(Intermediate):
    """This is also documented."""
```

My `index.rst` file looks as follows:

```
.. automodule:: mymodule
   :show-inheritance:
   :inherited-members:
```

Sphinx generates a nice API documentation for me. It includes the classes `Super` and `Sub`, with the appropriate comments. It does not include `Intermediate`, because it doesn't have a comment and I did not supply the `undoc-members` flag. This is because I don't want `Intermediate` to show up in the documentation.

My problem is this: Because I supply the `show-inheritance` flag, Sphinx displays the bases for each class; `object` for `Super` and `Intermediate` for `Sub`. Since `Intermediate` is undocumented, I do not want it to show up in the list of base classes. Instead, I'd like Sphinx to display the next documented class up in the inheritance tree, `Super`. In other words: I want Sphinx to display `Super`, not `Intermediate` as the base class of `Sub`.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: A great example of this is [`pyserial`](http://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/). I extended `serial.Serial`, which is just a front for one of the concrete implementations for each supported platform. I wanted the docs to show `serial.Serial` as my base, but instead it shows something like `serial.posixserial.Serial`, with no link since it is not officially documented.

Comment: have you tried something along the lines of `:exclude-members: Intermediate`?

Comment: This might be of interest: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#event-autodoc-process-bases (to be included in Sphinx 4.1). Issue: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/3014

Answer (score 3):

For this peculiar situation, where you want to "hide" the class inheritance, you can use [`autoclass`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directive-autoclass) to document each visible class instead of documenting the whole module.

For instance:

```
.. currentmodule:: demo

.. autoclass:: Super
   :members:

.. autoclass:: Sub
   :members:
```

Then you can add the `:show-inheritance:` flag to show inheritace to the class you want.

Quoting the doc:

> The automodule, autoclass and autoexception directives also support a flag option called show-inheritance. When given, a list of base classes will be inserted just below the class signature (when used with automodule, this will be inserted for every class that is documented in the module).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

Set inheritance as the default in the `autodoc` configuration:

```
autodoc_default_options = {
    # other options
    'show-inheritance': True
}
```

Then on a specific class unset the option:

.. autoclass:: SomeClass
:no-show-inheritance: